# Receiving data sent from client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project that has a C# app (running 24/7 as a server) on the client's machine). This app needs to send a file as a byte stream via POST to a server I am currently hosting on my home desktop.

Can this file be received by a C# app running on my server, or does it have to be as ASP app/page?

Also, I know how to send a bytestream via POST, but how will I set my server side app to listen for this incoming data?
I have never done something like this, so I'm looking for some pointers to get me started.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do with the file, and when it's uploaded, there is nothing wrong with using a tiny asp.net app to do this.

If the only way you can get the file to the server is via http POST, why write your own service/daemon to run a listener? Unless you have some reason not to run it in IIS, I would do it there. There is the full stack available that way for authentication and so on if you should happen to need it. Besides, if you have to upload files via http post, I would bet you will end up wanting other methods available via HTTP as well..

Comment: I have no reason not to use IIS, so I'll definitely look into it. If it makes life easy for me, thats all  want.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this guy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Using that, you'll create basically a mini HTTP server, listening on some port you specify. You'll then be able to post data to it, and process it accordingly (similar to if the processing code was in an ASPX code-behind).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your open to sending directly via TCP you can look at this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx) if you dont wanna go the HTTP way. I personaly like the [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) Class, for sending data over the network painfree.